# How to determine which running applications are using .Net

Tags: .net, wix, installation, iexpress

I have an application which uses thirdparty dlls that need .Net 4.0.
So, I packaged .Net exe using iexpress with my installer which is created using Wix.
However, later I came to know that it needs to reboot the machine after installing .Net 4.0 since some of its files may be in use.
I do not want my users to reboot the machine after installing my application.
The better way I thought is to display upfront what all running applications are using .Net so that they can close those applications and continue the installation without need to reboot.

How can I detect these running applications which are using .Net?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you’d have to do something similar to Process Explorer:

1. Call the [CLRCreateInstance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537633(v=vs.110).aspx) function with `CLSID_CLRMetaHost`.
2. Enumerate each process on the system, then call the [ICLRMetaHost::EnumerateLoadedRuntimes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233119(v=vs.110).aspx) method for each process.
3. For each runtime returned, call the [ICLRRuntimeInfo::GetVersionString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233129(v=vs.110).aspx) Method and check whether it returned the version string for .NET 4.0.